# Adding new column to existing DataFrame based on True / False validation

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a Boolean Data Frame which is the output of comparing two DF. Now I would like to add a column at the end  which says True if all the value in column is True and False of any of the value in the column is False.

[image]

I want to add True / False value based on entire column value. I want o/p like this:

[image: Output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`pandas.DataFrame.all`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) is made for this kind of operation, just have to specify `axis=1` to operate over columns:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"1": [True, False, False], "2": [True, True, False], "3": [True, False, False]})
df["T/F"] = df.all(axis=1)
print(df)
```

Ouput:

```
       1      2      3    T/F
0   True   True   True   True
1  False   True  False  False
2  False  False  False  False
```

Comment: Thanks you for such a quick response…
Sorry I can’t share my data as its confidential…. I’m sharing my piece of code which will compare two excel and create a output file… what I want is to insert a new column at the end and mention True / False based on column value.
Like this in the attached file.. Thanks a ton for your support and help..

Comment: quarterly = pd.read_excel('HCPC2022_JANcompare.xlsx','Quarterly')
annual = pd.read_excel('HCPC2022_JANcompare.xlsx','Ann match')
comparison_matrix = quarterly.values==annual.values
#Indexing the Cell with False value
rows,cols = np.where(comparison_matrix == False)
for item in zip(rows,cols):
    quarterly.iloc[item[0], item[1]] = 'Annual: {} Vs Quarterly: {}'.format(annual.iloc[item[0], item[1]],quarterly.iloc[item[0], item[1]]) 
quarterly.to_excel(r'./compare' +'.xlsx',sheet_name='Compare',index=False,header=True)

Comment: i have added new  attachment named output.  Please refer to the new image...

Comment: Its really hard to grasp the actual issue with the redacted data. Consider making a mockup of the issue that you can share with the output you want to get. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask